# Using Meshbuilder with AR

Tags: google-project-tango

Is it possible to use the Meshbuilder with the AR camera?  I'm using the Meshbuilder with AR but I don't see the mesh. Breakpoint so show the mesh is being built. My theory is the projection used for the AR camera doesn't match what's used for the depth camera and meshing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say take the world position of the mesh transform and calculate its yaw and pitch against the cameras look vector - if that angle is bigger than fieldofview/2, then the mesh is offscreen, otherwise something else is wrong - and you can always do lookat(mesh.transform.position) as well

Comment: By pausing the meshing and looking around, I discovered that the mesh is 90 degrees off on the Z rotation. However, when it becomes visible the Tango crashes. And crashes HARD--sometimes I have to uninstall the app to get it to work. Also, the depth camera really slows the frame rate of the video as well. I think that perhaps the device freaks out if you're not done processing the depth frame before another one comes in?

Comment: Oh god yes -  do NOT process data during acquisition - just get it into another buffer and give control back to Tango - otherwise the thing has a complete fit :-)

Comment: Also, in general the mesher doesn't work that well - crash happy - I was amazed by how long it ran for JLee in the demo -  worked with it a while, never did get it to be stable, it seemed something involved in mesh update - gave up because I didn't need to draw the isosurface and had a better voxelizer anyway